# Processing not detecting dead flies

Tags: java, processing

been a lurker for a while, first time posting :)

I'm currently working on a little game for uni. I have the the majority of it done, but the "problem" that I'm running into is getting lost to tunnel vision. I was hoping someone would be able to point me in the right direction.

I have a program (code below) that prints an image of a fly to the canvas. A fly swatter follows the mouse and, when a fly is within range of the swatter and the mouse is pressed, the fly gets rekt.

The issue that I'm encountering is that the program is still recognising dead flies as having collision detection, and so whether I click on a dead fly of a live fly, the collision is still detected and a new fly is spawned.

Any help would be appreciated :) Thanks!

```
PImage fly, flybye, swatter, swatted;
float[] fX, fY;  // fly locations array
float[] swat;  // fly swatted binary boolean array, 1 = swatted, 0 = not swatted
int score = 0;  // increments when swatted.

void setup(){
  size(800,400);
  fX = new float[0];
  fY = new float[0];
  swat = new float[0];
  fly = loadImage("fly.png");
  flybye = loadImage("flybye.png");
  swatter = loadImage("swatter.png");
  swatted = loadImage("swatted.png");
  
  fX = append(fX, random(1, 800)); //first fly - random location
  fY = append(fY, random(1, 400));
  swat = append(swat, 0); // used as a boolean and matches to each individual fly, 0 = fly not 
  swatted, 1 = swatted.
}

void populate(){ // draw the flies in memory to the screen.
  for(int i = 0; i < fX.length; i++){
    if(swat[i] == 1){ // if swatted
      flybye.resize(30, 30);// resize the fly image and place based on fx/fy array values
      image(flybye, fX[i], fY[i]);
    } else { // not swatted
      fly.resize(30, 30);
      image(fly, fX[i], fY[i]);
    }
    
  }
}

void collisionDetect(){ //collision detection - detect collision between swatter and fly
  for(int i = 0; i < swat.length; i++){ // bounding box detection
    if(dist(fX[i], fY[i], mouseX, mouseY) < 50){ // condition should look at location of mouse 
                                                    and individual coordinates in fX and fY
      swat[i] = 1; // swatted
      fX = append(fX, random(1, 800)); //new fly placed in random location when old fly dies.
      fY = append(fY, random(1, 400));
      swat =append(swat, 0); // new fly not swatted
      score++; //increment score
    }
  }
}

void draw(){ 
  background(255);
  populate(); // draw flys to screen.
  fill(0);
  textSize(20);
  text(score, 5, 20);// set a text size and location for the score.
  if(mousePressed) { // image swap
    collisionDetect();
    image(swatted, mouseX - 30, mouseY - 30);   //draw swatter image to around mouse locaiton - might want to play with this to get it to look right.
  }else{
    image(swatter, mouseX - 30, mouseY - 30); // if not pressed then alternative image.
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you test if the fly is swatted in your collision detection:
`if(swat[i] == 0 && dist(fX[i], fY[i], mouseX, mouseY) < 50){`

Comment: Wow. See? Tunnel vision! I was messing around with limiting mouse clicks but I didn't even think to check there. Many breaths in, many breaths out. Thank you so much :)